# Prove that Waring's number $G(k) \geq 4k$ for $k=2^m$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that Waring's number $G(k) \geq 4k$ for $k=2^m$.

$G(k)$ is the smallest number such that every sufficient large $n$ can be represented by sum of $G(k)$ k-th power.

$G(k) \geq 4k$ then means there exist infinite number that cannot be represented by $4k-1$ k-th powers.

This statement is said to be 'well-known' and 'easy to see' in many papers about Waring's number, but I cannot see the reason and fail to find a proof.

Actually in particular I am interested in the case $k=4$.

Thanks for any helps.

Note: Consider the modulus over $4k$ is not enough, even $x^k \equiv 0, 1$ mod $4k$ only. $4k-1$ of them can adds up to any number between $0$ and $4k-1$ mod $4k$. i.e. covering all numbers.

Comment: With $k=2^m$, look at the values of $a^k$ modulo $4k$ for different $a$.  What do you notice?

Comment: Consider the modulus over $4k$ is not enough, even $x^4 \equiv 0, 1$ mod $4k$ only. $4k-1$ of them can adds up to any number between $0$ and $4k-1$ mod $4k$. i.e. covering all numbers. @mjqxxxx

Comment: Not sure about $k=4$.  For all larger powers of $2$, $a^k \equiv 0$ mod $8k$ when $a$ is even, showing that a number equal to $4k$ mod $8k$ can’t be the sum of only even numbers to the $k$-th power... you need at least one odd number, hence at least $4k$ of them.

Comment: Thanks, this is really a nice proof.@mjqxxxx

Comment: The proof for $k=4$ is similar, again using the modular identity $x^4\equiv 0,1$ mod $16$.  If $a$ is a multiple of $16$ and expressed as a sum of fewer than $16$ fourth powers, then they must all be even: $a=x_1^4+\cdots+x_{15}^4=(2y_1)^4+\cdots+(2y_{15})^4=16(y_1^4+\cdots+y_{15}^4)$, so $a/16$ must also be a sum of fewer than $16$ fourth powers.  But $31$ cannot be expressed as a sum of fewer than $16$ fourth powers (easy to check), and so neither can $16\cdot 31$, $16^2\cdot 31$, and so on.